# Is it possible to have a user change an array value in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to have an array of "default" values already loaded into my iOS app, but give the user the ability to change those values based on their personal preference. For example:

```
var arrayOfChoices = ["red","blue","green"]
```

Can I have a field where the user enters a value (userEnteredValue) "purple" and then set `arrayOfChoice[2] = userEnteredValue` resulting in

```
arrayOfChoices = ["red", "blue", "purple"]
```

I don't need the specific code on how to do this, I am just working on the functionality of my app at the moment, but I am just wondering if this would be possible and if the new arrayOfChoices would then be store in the apps code for that user until the array is changed again?

Comment: just change it from "let" to "var".

Comment: One approach would be to save the default values (["red","blue","green"]) as `UserDefaults` the first time the app runs.  After that, load `arrayOfChoices` from `UserDefaults` on startup.  When the user indicates a different set of choices, update `UserDefaults` and reload.

Comment: IOW, you can't change the app's code while running but you can give it new data.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to set some samples to give you an overview of what you can do with `UserDefaults` by storing and retrieving your `key` of array of colors name as of in this example through `shared_pref_colors` key name. You can give it whatever name you like to this key, just keep it consistent:

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
UserDefaults.standard.set(colors, forKey: "shared_pref_colors")
print("Stored initial: \(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "shared_pref_colors"))")

colors[2] = "purple"
UserDefaults.standard.set(colors, forKey: "shared_pref_colors")
print("Retrieved after storing purple: \(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "shared_pref_colors"))")

var colorsRetrieved = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "shared_pref_colors") as! [String]
print("Retrieved before manipulation: \(colorsRetrieved)")

colorsRetrieved[0] = "yellow"
UserDefaults.standard.set(colorsRetrieved, forKey: "shared_pref_colors")
print("Retrieved after storing yellow \(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "shared_pref_colors"))")
```

Which will print out this:

> ```
> Stored initial: Optional([red, blue, green])
> Retrieved after storing purple: Optional([red, blue, purple])
> Retrieved before manipulation: ["red", "blue", "purple"]
> Retrieved after storing yellow Optional([yellow, blue, purple])
> ```